# figure('Position',[x y width height]) won't go over height 800

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using an external monitor. My notebook has display of height 800 px, but monitor has over 1000 px. If I'm running the script on external monitor

```
screenSize = get(0,'MonitorPositions');
figureSize = screenSize(4);
figure('Position',[0 0 figureSize figureSize])
```

the size of the new figure won't go over the size of notebook display. Is there a way how to fix this?

---

EDIT

I have found that if I start MATLAB while having already set the external monitor as an output device, the script runs just ok. Is there any way how to reset settings, that are responsible, before running the skript?

Comment: What does `won't go over the size of notebook display` mean? What are the values of `screenSize`? Is `screenSize(4)` the correct value?

Comment: The height of the figure won't be greater than 800 if I set it greater. Numbers in variables are correct.

Comment: I don't care if you think the numbers are correct, I want to know what they are.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
figureSize = screenSize(monitorNumber,4);
```

As screenSize(4) will give you the 4th element in the matrix - same as `screenSize = screenSize(:)`

Answer (score 2):

By default figures are displayed on the primary display. If you want to force Matlab to show figures on the external monitor, you need to set the `DefaultFigurePosition` to a value that is actually on the secondary monitor.

Therefore, let's say you create a figure and drag it on the external monitor. Then you can fetch the current position and set it to the default like so:

```
FigPos = get(gcf,'Position');

set(0, 'DefaultFigurePosition', FigPos);
```

Then figures will subsequently appear on the external monitor with a size that fits. That's not perfect since you need to create a figure, drag it and then delete it and it's only valid for your current session. However you can add the previous lines of code in your `startup.m` file to do it automatically.

Hope that helps somehow!